# Using snowflake in aws lamda by adding snowflake connector dependencies as layer

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add `snowflake-connector-python` version 2.7.9 as a layer in aws lambda.
I am getting this error
`Unable to import module lambda_function: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28 not found (required by /opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so)`

Steps I have tried
`docker run -v /Users/local/Documents/docker_test:/working -it --rm ubuntu`

once inside i tried

1. `apt-get update`
2. then install python 3.9 using link `https://exchangetuts.com/how-to-install-python39-on-linux-ubuntu-terminal-1639972230035814`
3. `apt install python3-virtualenv`
4. virtualenv snowflake_test
5. source snowflake_test/bin/activate
6. python3 --version
7. sudo apt install python3-pip
8. python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip
9. sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev
10. mkdir -p lambda_layers/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
11. cd lambda_layers/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages
12. pip3 install snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9 -t .

Then i zip the `/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages` contents and create a layer in aws. And i function is simple

```
import json
import snowflake.connector

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Some of things i had to do to get to this error

1. I had to install cffi as i was getting `No module named '_cffi_backend'`
2. Had to remove cyrptography dependecies as i had version 36 and reinstall again to get 38
3. python3-virtualenv seems to install python 3.10.x version as well. So the docker image has both python 3.10 and 3.9. Snowflake doc says it only works with 3.9
   I change the added alias to `python` and `python3` to point to `python3.9`

How to i get this error `/lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28` fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to specify an older cryptography version in the lambda layer (pip install cryptography==3.4.8). For me this solved the issue, hope this helps you too!